# HTTP service returning wrong intent despite correct training

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have a strange situation. For some utterances, LUIS has been trained to return GetGenericResponse intent. Eg., thank you, you are nice, etc. (screenshot below)

[image]

But in the JSON, LUIS is returning the wrong intent (GetBotIntroduction) for them. This is even after manually clicking the “Train” button and republishing the service.

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you published your trained model?

Comment: I did, as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had posted this question on LUIS MSDN forums as well. Someone from Microsoft responded with a solution that worked for me.

> LUIS uses a machine learning model to make its predictions and in some
>   edge cases when two intents are similar it can get confused on certain
>   utterances even if they are labelled as one intent or the other.
>
> To fix this issue you need only to add 1 or 2 more labels to
>   “GetEducationHelp” that are similar to “learning about ai”, such as “I
>   am learning about ai”. Once you retrain after adding that label the
>   model should learn to distinguish between both intents sufficiently.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/75ea0e86-a4d0-4aa6-bfaa-054d899079a4/http-endpoint-returning-wrong-intent-despite-correct-training?forum=LUIS